# Java BCEL getfield instruction

Tags: java, field, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, bcel

**Goal**

I have a class `A` with a method called `getStr`. I want to replicate the code inside the method using a `Instructionlist` in BCEL.

```
public class A {
    private String str;

    private String getStr() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I have tried the following code but with no success as it causes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when later running the modified class `A`. I think that the `GETFIELD` is causing this as it works without it (other instructions slightly modified).

```
il.append(new ALOAD(0)); // Load .this
il.append(new GETFIELD(poolGen.addFieldref("A", "str","Ljava/lang/String;"))); // Causes problem
il.append(new ARETURN()); // Return the field

MethodGen methodGen = new MethodGen(
                Constants.ACC_PRIVATE,
                Type.STRING,
                null,
                null,
                "getStr",
                "A",
                il,
                poolGen);

il.setPositions();
methodGen.setMaxLocals();
methodGen.setMaxStack();
methodGen.removeLineNumbers();

myClassGen.replaceMethod(macMethod, methodGen.getMethod());
myClassGen.update();
```

**Question**

So what is the correct way of creating a getfield instruction with BCEL?

**Note:**
I create the `private String str;` field using BCEL aswell, with the code:

```
FieldGen fieldGen1 = new FieldGen(Constants.ACC_PRIVATE, Type.STRING, "str", poolGen);
myClassGen.addField(fieldGen1.getField());
myClassGen.update();
```

Comment: Did you try disassembling the bytecode created by `javac` and comparing?

Comment: yes, unfortunately i could not see any errors. Whats weird is that the exeption gets thrown even though i never call the getStr() method. Just the public static void main(..